# What does the gtky tag mean?

Tags: discussion, tags

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301/your-favourite-algorithm-and-the-lesson-it-taught-you) on SO has tag `gtky`.   Does anybody know (a) what it means, and (b) any reason why a tag with no clear meaning should exist?

Comment: Looks like the latest attempt to let us filter out the deluge of idiotic "bikeshed" questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Getting To Know You"

A community-building question: answers are required only to relate the personal experiences of their authors; problem-solving, discussion, or aggregation of results not required.

(it's a meta tag, but somewhat more descriptive than [opinion])

Comment: And apparently known to the relatively cool kids (i.e., those cooler than me), which is admittedly a large number of people.

Comment: @David Apparently i wasn't cool enough to know it either, i had to look it up

Comment: Eh... I doubt it's as well-known as it should be. Pretty sure I introduced the tag many months ago, but it never took off like "subjective" or "discussion". I tried more self-descriptive tags ("tell-me-a-story"), but those died even faster. I suspect it's akin to not wanting your porn showing up in the mail with "PORN INSIDE" stamped across the wrapper - anyone with "gtky" in their top tags would be a fairly obvious bar-fly.

Comment: I remember seeing it in fall '08, if I'm not mistaken. I thought it was Adam Davis, but it could have been you.

Comment: @mmyers: I was *using* it as early as Sept. '08, but can't recall for sure if I actually created it or not. Gave it up in favor of closing, which then was rejiggered to not work for this purpose anyway. Started using it again today while going through [opinion] questions - some of these will probably never stay closed or deleted, so they might as well have tags.

Answer (score 0):

[From an online dictionary](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/GTKY)

> GTKY : Getting to Know You

Seems weird it would be attached?